# How to connect Remix desktop to connect to MetaMask?

Tags: remix, metamask

I downloaded the desktop version of Remix, and am trying to connect it to the main network. I can do this in the web version of Remix easily, opening up MetaMask on my browser. However, in the desktop version, when I toggle 'injected Web3' for the environment, I get the error: 'No injected web3 provider found. Make sure your provider (eg MetaMask) is active and running'.

How do I connect MetaMask to the Remix Ethereum IDE for Windows desktop?

Comment: First Login to metamask with your password. Keep the metamask opened and then again open the remix ide.

Comment: MetaMask is a browser extension you can only use it from within the browser. My guess is that stand alone Remix uses electron so it should be possible to run MetaMask but you have to do some work https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5365.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it's possible. https://medium.com/remix-ide/getting-started-with-remix-desktop-5f6380568d12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy a contract with **Remix IDE** via **MetaMask** you need to activate, setup and use the *Wallet Connect* plugin that is already shipped with Remix app. After this *Wallet Connect* will show up as a new option in the deploy-screen (in addition to *Injected Web3* that is not working with Remix desktop).

A detailed instruction for using *Wallet Connect* with **Remix IDE** is given in [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/125147/95734) also here on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, make sure you carry out the entire process under The Chrome Browser. MetaMask doesn't seem to be able to connect with Remix, through The Microsoft Edge Browser.