# Using Remix Web3 Provider with Infura

Tags: remix, walletconnect

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract to an Ethereum testnet (e.g., Rinkeby) via Remix Desktop. I have an RPC url provided by Infura, and I'm using this RPC url for Web3 Provider. Remix Environment does switch to Rinkeby successfully; however, I'm not able to add a new account. It asks for a passphrase, and when I enter some arbitrary passphrase, it gives me an error: "Cannot create an account: Error: Returned error: The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available"

Am I doing something wrong here? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We cant help you unless you provide detail such as code, exact command you enter, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For deployment of your contract with **Remix IDE** you need to use the *WalletConnect* plugin (which comes already along with *Remix*). Just follow the steps below:

1. Activate plugin "Wallet Connect"
   Click on the plug-icon to switch to Plugin Manager, search for plugin and click "Activate".
2. In the added "Wallet Connect" tab enter your *Infura* project ID, press "Connect to a wallet" and select *WalletConnect* connection method.
3. A window with a QR code pops up. Scan with your *MetaMask* mobile app and allow *Remix* to connect with *MetaMask* by approving the appearing request on your mobile device.
   Important: before QR scanning select the account and network in *MetaMask* you want to use for deployment.
4. Now the "Wallet Connect" tab in *Remix* shows your account address and network.
5. Change to DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS screen and you will find a new entry "Wallet Connect" in "Environment" data field. Select and *Remix* will show the chosen network in small letters below. Furthermore, your wallet address is inserted in account data field. So you are ready to deploy!

Important: make sure you disable "Personal Mode for web3 provider" in settings menu. With personal mode on your wallet address will not show up in deployment screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the readme they mention that currently to deploy to a public chain you have to use the walletconnect plugin, [Deploying to a public testnet with Injected Web3 & Metamask](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop#deploying-to-a-public-testnet-with-injected-web3--metamask):

> Remix Desktop does not have access to the Metamask - the browser plugin - so deploying to a public chain currently involves using the Wallet Connect plugin. In contract, Remix IDE - the web app has easy access to the Metamask browser plugin.