# Cannot change the Environment to `wallet connect` in remix desktop IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to connect to Metamask from my remix desktop IDE.
I follow  these URL [Using Remix Web3 Provider with Infura](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123485/using-remix-web3-provider-with-infura)

But after doing all the steps successfully, at point 5,when in DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS screen I choose  "Wallet Connect" in "Environment" data ,it doesn't change and selected to the default environment "Remix VM (Merge)".
I'm using remix desktop version 0.31.2.Attaching the screenshot also.
[image]

Please suugest me what's wrong in my configuration.